# Toggling state in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a beginner to do list app, and I'm running into an issue when trying to add a method to allow a user to change the status of a to do item from not completed to completed

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Todo from './Todo.js'
import "./styles.css";

const [todos, setTodos] = useState(
    [{id: 0, task: 'Laundry', isCompleted: false},
     {id: 1, task: 'Dishes', isCompleted: true},
     {id: 2, task: 'Clean room', isCompleted: false}])
  
  const completeTodo = (index) => {
    newtodos = [...todos];
    newtodos[index].isCompleted = true;
    setTodos(newtodos)
  }
  const todoList = todos.map(object => {
    return(
     <Todo 
      key={object.id} 
      taskName={object.task} 
      isCompleted={object.isCompleted} 
      clickHandler={completeTodo}
    /> 
   )
 }) 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>To Do List App</h1>
      <div className="TodoList">
        {todoList}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

of course, I pass the completeTodo method to my Todo component.

Todo.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Todo(props) {
  return (
      <div className="TodoItem">
        <label> {props.taskName}
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          checked={props.isCompleted ? true : false}
          onClick={props.clickHandler(props.key)}/>
        </label>
        

      </div>
  )
```

But when I test the functionality by clicking on a checkbox, I get the following error message:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'isCompleted' of undefined'
The error points to the second line of my completeTodo method in App.js. I've attached an image of the error message.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVT0c.png)

Comment: The `key` prop in React is a special one, the component doesn't have access to it. Pass the ID in as a custom prop, like `id={object.id}`. Also, in `Todo.js`, your `onClick` prop in the input should be a function, not a function call. Like `onClick={() => props.clickHandler(props.id)}/>`

Comment: Ah i see, thanks so much! 
I also made the mistake of not adding a 'const' before my variable name of newtodos in my completeTodo method, which also caused issues. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Jayce444 I finally got it working thanks to your suggestions, really appreciate it!